# custom class to CoreData and back

Tags: swift, core-data

Im parsing a jason via Decodable and creating an array of objects but cant find a way to save it in core data,

here is the model :

```
import UIKit

public struct  Movie : Decodable {
    let title : String
    let image : String
    let rating : Double
    let releaseYear : Int
    let genre : Array<String>


    init(title: String ,image : String , rating : Double, releaseYear : Int, genre : Array<String>) {
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.rating = rating
        self.releaseYear = releaseYear
        self.genre = genre

    }
    init() {
        self.title = "title"
        self.image = "image"
        self.rating = 0.0
        self.releaseYear = 0000
        self.genre = ["",""]
    }
}
```

and here is what I did so far

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
             guard err == nil else { return }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let movies = try JSONDecoder().decode([Movie].self, from: data)
                self.movieList = movies
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume()
```

tried to create entities with all kinds of attributes types but all in vain

Comment: There is no core data code here and it is quite unclear what your exact issue is.

Comment: Im sorry, there is no core data code because it didnt work, I have an variable called movieList wich holds all of the "movies" and i tried to make an Transformable and BinaryData types of attribute but its dosent mach and i dont know how to convert it to the core data not talking about using it to populate a colle tion view

Comment: I have a variable movieList that hold an array out of the json im getting, and i cant save it in the core data no metter wich attribute im trying to make to save it,  I tried binary data and transformable.

Comment: Don't persist the list itself, create a movie entity instead and store the individual movies. It would make much more sense in my opinion.

Comment: I tried it as well, but wen trying to get it back i got only 1 movie out, and everytime i open the app again it filed it by one movie at a time and always the first one. can you show the way i get all the movies outside to populate a variable i can use to fill the collectionView ? its title-String, imageurl-String, rating-Double, genre-String and releaseyear-Int

Comment: This is basic stuff if you want to work with core data, go through an online tutorial [like this one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/173972/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial-2)